# How to compute $x^{1/y}$?

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature

I'm reading this paper: 
[Traceable Ring Signature](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/389.pdf).

I see this in section 4:

$A_1=(\frac{\sigma_s}{A_0})^{1/s}$

My question is how to compute this, such as:

$x^{1/y}$

where $x$ is a generator.

Comment: $x$ is a generator of what? A cyclic group, probably. Of what order?

Comment: $x$ is a generator of  multiplicative group of prime order $q$, the paper didn't give more details.

Comment: Compute the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) modulo the order using the extended euclidean algorithm. You could read an introduction to RSA where d=1/e and phi(n) = order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^{1/y}$ is the $y$th root of $x$, *i.e.*, the element $w$ that satisfies $w^y =x$.

If $x$ generates a group of prime order $q$, it can be shown that this element $w$ is unique and equals $x^z$ where $z$ is the inverse of $y$ modulo $q$. (One way to show this is to use the fact that $x^a = x^b$ if and only if $a \equiv b \pmod q$.)